# How can I programmatically delete a custom menu?

Tags: 8, navigation

I'm writing a `hook_deploy_N` that moves a bunch of menu items from a deprecated custom menu to some newer ones. So far, so good. After moving the items, I want to delete the old menu, but can't figure out how. `\Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeStorage` has a `delete` function that **may** be  what I'm looking for, but the `\Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeStorage` object is housed inside the `\Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuLinkTree`, which I can at least load, but has protected status, and I don't see a way to get to it. Plus, I'm not not 100% convinced that's what I want any way.

Answer (score 0):

Since menus are configuration items, my poking into `\Drupal\Core\Menu\MenuTreeStorage::delete()` was wrong. You delete a custom menu thusly:

```
\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('system.menu.name-of-custom-menu')->delete();
```

Note that I'm assuming the menu is empty. I don't know what would happen if you deleted a menu that had menu items in it, whether they'd be orphaned or deleted.